# Microsoft Word output is substantially different from print preview; probably compatibility issue Word 2013 vs. Word 2003 template

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing, compatibility

I'm using `Save As` in `Word 2013` or `DoPDF` to convert a Word document to PDF. When I see Word document print preview, everything is OK.  But when I convert it to PDF or simply print it to paper, it comes out substantially different.  Suppose that I have 20 lines in a page. Now I have 14 lines in the outputted page. I changed page margins to normal and the page size is A4. Everything is default. Everything in the page layout changes; position of shapes, number of lines etc.  I think I have less space in the output than in Word. I have this problem in `DoPDF`, `Save As PDF` in Word 2013, and directly printed output.  I checked it in two different Word 2013, but I have the same problem in both Words.

The problem appears to be document-specific.  I don't have this problem other files.  This is a .docx file that was a thesis template in Word 2003.  I think this is a problem with compatibility mode.

I also tried creating a blank page in Word 2013 and copying all of the document contents into it to convert it to a Word 2013 document, but I had the same problem.  However, if I paste with the option to keep text only, everything is correct; the PDF, Print and preview then match. I think this is a problem with template.

How do I get Word 2013 to accurately import the document?

Comment: you have to understand, this conversion process is never going to be a 100%. Since we don't see the source of your document, we can't help.

Comment: What happens if you print a page to paper?  Does the output match the print preview or the PDF?  How are you viewing the PDF results?  Are you using an unusual font or the extended character set used for foreign languages?

Comment: @fixer1234 The print page is same as pdf. No. There isn't any problem in fonts. I think i have fewer space in pdf. Some lines of every page go to another page.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in Word, itself.  It isn't displaying the print preview the same way it's handling the page.

Comment: @fixer1234. Yes. But I checked it in two different word 2013 but I have same problem in both words!!

Comment: So the document, itself, is a normal Word file (like .docx?)?  You open the file in either installation of Word, print it to the printer, and it comes out different from how it looks on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is OK when you paste text only, most probably it is due to formatting. This is how word handles formatting - when you copy/paste from the other document you are copying the formatting too (it transfers all the formatting from the original document and adds it to the receiving document.

I see 2 ways to fix this:

1. Instead of copy/paste use **Insert > Object > Text from file** function:[image]
2. If #1 doesn't work, you should try using section breaks before and after where you will be pasting the content. Then check/change the settings for that particular section.

Comment: Thank you for answer. That was true. It was a formatting problem. I removed all section breaks. Now everything is normal.